# Persistent Browser Sign In Prompt Popup

Tags: cpanel, plesk

I've just got my PHP website back up and running on hosting, but there's this annoying sign-in prompt that keeps popping up when I visit the site. Plus, if I try to ignore it, I get hit with a 401 error. What gives?

[image: sign in popup]

Has anyone encountered something like this before? Any ideas on what might be causing it and how I can fix it? I'm a bit lost here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you might have authentication written in .htaccess file. Check the link https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216363187-Password-protecting-your-site-with-an-htaccess-file

Comment: You have http authentication emabled on your site. Most likely this was configured on webserver level (like .htaccess files for apache, other webservers have different configuration methods) or you could have written it as part of your main php file - although I would sincerely hope you would be aware had you done something like this from code.

Comment: doubt it. the only thing left written in the .htaccess is `Options -Indexes` , at least the in main folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause. It's because I'm trying to call images from a folder named `img`. **Changing the folder name** resolve the problem.

Might be server configuration restrict the `img` folder.